# Filling an empty value in Scala Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am currently working with a dataframe right now in scala, and can't figure out how to fill a column with a `Seq.empty[Row]` value if the value in that row is `null`. I understand there is the `df.na.fill` function, however it seems to only handle strings, doubles, or ints from my understanding.

Essentially, I want to be able to fill the null row with a `Seq.empty[Row]`, for a nested field. I'm sure this is possible, however it seems like I can't find anything like it online.

Table example --

`+-----------+-------------------+-----------+---------+------------------+
|      field|             field2|                      |            values|
+-----------+-------------------+-----------+----------+------------------+
|     stuff2|            stuff 2|                      |       null       |
|     stuff1|             stuff1|                      |   [val 1,val2,..]|
+-----------+-------------------+-----------+----------+------------------+`

Essentially, I want that null to turn into an empty array like so: `[]`. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using `udf` and `coalesce` like below.

```
val df = Seq(("stuff2","stuff2",null), ("stuff2","stuff2",Array("value1","value2")),("stuff3","stuff3",Array("value3"))).toDF("field","field2","values")
df.show()

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val array_ = udf(() => Array.empty[String])

val df2 = df.withColumn("values", coalesce(df("values"), array_()))
df2.show()
```

Comment: There's a lot of difficulty in converting a `null` to empty `Sequence` of `Row` perfectly, because `coalesce` is dependent on the type of the column being correct. I'm having trouble inferring the type of the column effectively, and I think that's a different question. However your point still stands, so thank you for the answer.

Comment: Clever hack using `udf` to inject non-literal value!